# Git sync with latest release

Tags: git, github, git-svn, fetch, git-pull

I have several releases with different tag names (e.g v1.0, v1.0.5 and v2.4 etc). I only publish a release when my project is at a stable condition.

On a separate machine, I want to pull the latest version that is 'stable', that is to say, the latest release that has been made.

Is there a way to achieve this through Git?

Comment: how are you determining the 'latest' ?  By date the tag was creating, or by the highest version number in the tag name or something else ?

Comment: Preferably, I would like to sync with the newest release by date it was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using tag objects (`git tag -m`), then `git fetch` to sync the repos, then do `git for-each-ref --sort=taggerdate --format '%(refname:short)' refs/tags | tail -1` to get the most recent tag and check that out.

Comment: Brilliant - this answers the question perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If your tags are named consistently with version numbers as your example that `v1.0` < `v1.0.5` < `v2.4`,  you can just get the last line from `git tag` as the latest.

So the command should be as follows, assuming the remote reference name is `origin`

```
git fetch --tags origin
git checkout $(git tag | tail -1)
```

To make it one line command.

```
git fetch --tags origin && git checkout $(git tag | tail -1)
```

Comment: This is really good too, thanks. I think that the Andrew's answer gives me more flexibility in the naming of my releases, but otherwise your method works just fine.